# Animate Element on mouserOver to slide down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a small page with some h2- and p-Elements.
I have a div-Elemnt which looks like a dot.
Everytime the user moves the mouse over a h2-Element the dot-Element jumps to the same height as the header.

I used Javascript to solve this problem.
The code works as expected but the movement looks like a jump.
Now I'm trying to make the movement of the dot looking smooth like a slide down.

I couldn't find a way with JavaScript and couldn't figure out how to solve it with CSS.

```js
function moveBulletpoint(id) {
  var elementToBeMoved = document.getElementById("handle");
  elementToBeMoved.style.top = document.getElementById(id).offsetTop + 'px'
}
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style: none
}

h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

h2:hover {
  opacity: 0.6
}

.gld-line {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #ededee;
  height: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.et_pb_code_inner {
  position: relative;
}

.gld-dot {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #222222;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: 2s left;
}

.gld-line {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #ededee;
  height: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="et_pb_code_inner">
    <div id="handle" class="gld-dot"></div>
    <div class="gld-line"></div>
  </div>

  <div style="padding-left: 100px">
    <p>
      <h2 onmouseover="moveBulletpoint(this.id);" id="firstItem">HEADER 1</h2>
      Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! In a comic, you know how you can tell who the arch-villain's going to be? He's the exact opposite of the hero.
    </p>
    <p>
      <h2 onmouseover="moveBulletpoint(this.id);" id="secondItem">HEADER 2</h2>
      Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! In a comic, you know how you can tell who the arch-villain's going to be? He's the exact opposite of the hero.
    </p>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)'s property of the `.gld-dot` class to `top`. The [transition-property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property) is the property that will be animated by the transition. Since you use `left` but change `top` no transition is applied.

```js
const handle = document.querySelector('#handle');

const headers = document.querySelectorAll('h2')
  .forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
      handle.style.top = `${e.currentTarget.offsetTop}px`;
    });
  });
```

```css
.gld-dot {
  display: none;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style: none
}

h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

h2:hover {
  opacity: 0.6
}

.gld-line {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #ededee;
  height: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.et_pb_code_inner {
  position: relative;
}

.gld-dot {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #222222;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

.gld-line {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #ededee;
  height: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="et_pb_code_inner">
    <div id="handle" class="gld-dot"></div>
    <div class="gld-line"></div>
  </div>

  <div style="padding-left: 100px">
    <p>
      <h2>HEADER 1</h2>
      Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! In a comic, you know how you can tell who the arch-villain's going to be? He's the exact opposite of the hero.
    </p>
    <p>
      <h2>HEADER 2</h2>
      Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! In a comic, you know how you can tell who the arch-villain's going to be? He's the exact opposite of the hero.
    </p>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Wow That Easy! Thank You! BTW can you tell me if my solution is state of the art or is there a better way to solve it? maybe without javascript?

Comment: You're welcome. You can clean your code a bit. Avoid inline styles. Use `Element.addEventListener()` and don't inline the mouse handlers. And use `document.querySelectorAll()` to get a reference to elements. I made some changes on the JS side. See if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you alot I will analyze your changes and try to learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your existing css `.gld-dot`:

```
.gld-dot {
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```